# C++ Client Calling C# COM Server returns System.FormatException

Tags: .net, com, clr, marshalling, com-interop

I have a C# COM Interface defined as

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("EB6602D5-8458-4733-8F0A-05A88FEEB42F")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void Initialize(string szPath, uint uiAddress,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object pEventsImpl,   //Interface pointer for my COM Svr Callback
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            out object ppCommunication); //Interface for Client to Access Server 
}
```

The generated tlb for this COM interface is

```
    interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
    HRESULT _stdcall Initialize(
                    [in] BSTR szPath, 
                    [in] unsigned long uiAddress, 
                    [in] IUnknown* pEventsImpl, 
                    [out] IUnknown** ppCommunication);
}
```

and in the C++ Client Code i call the C# COM as

```
hr = pInterface->Initialize(    strPath, iAddress, m_Events, &pUnk);
```

however i received the following exceptions

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
First-chance exception at 0x7c812aeb in MyClient.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352. Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0012f0ac..
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in MyClient.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in MyClient.exe
```

Have i Done Anything wrong here? And What is this System.FormatException?

[Updated] Addtinal Information **
I have tried to compile the C++ code with the /clr (Common Language Runtime support) option, it seems to work. However, i want to know if it is possible not to compile my C++ code with common language runtime support as i have some retrictions since i am using an existing C++ client which i donot want to recompile using different configurations

thanks

Comment: There's nothing very unusual about an exception like this.  Managed code and particularly the .NET Framework uses exceptions heavily to generate diagnostics.  FormatException is an everyday exception like that, raised when you try to convert a string to a number by the Parse() method and the string can't be converted.  You need to fix the C# code or fix the data it processes.  Consider TryParse() instead.  Use the managed debugger to find the bad statement.